# Add trailer to csv using Linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed

There are let's say 44 records in my csv file. I want to add the word:

`TRAILER,44`

In my CSV file using linux command. How to do it?

I am using `wc -l myfilename.csv | cut -d' ' -f1 >> myfilename.csv` for word count. I can add the word `TRAILER` and word count on the next line, but was wondering if I could get them on the same line.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: I am using wc -l myfilename.csv | cut -d' ' -f1 >> myfilename.csv for word count.

Comment: I can add the word Trailer and word count on the next line, but was wondering if i could get them on the same line.

Comment: What's wrong with `echo "TRAILER,$(wc -l < myfilename.csv)" >> myfilename.csv`?

Answer (score 4):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '1; END{print "TRAILER," NR}' file
```

print all lines and at the end print trailer with line count.

To replace the original file:

```
$ awk ... file > tmp && mv tmp file
```